# Excel formula/lookup to pull data from separate worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

All I need it to do is update Columns O10, Q10, S10, U10, W10, Y10,AA10 with the amount of hours for the relevant day from the 'Hours' sheet and then Columns P10, R10, T10, V10, X10, Z10 to pull from the 'Hours' sheet (but this one will need to cross reference the absence codes in AF11-AG19.

I hope I have explained this well enough, if there is a formula/look up that can do this the result would be the same as what I have typed in manually for Tom Smith.

Thanks in advance ,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

These are very basic Excel concepts. Cells are identified by cell references. So on the default worksheet, let's say it's Sheet1, the upper left hand cell is A1.

To reference from a different location on a different sheet, you need to use extended addresses. Let me use a very simple example. The extended address format is essentially the sheet name, an exclamation point, and then the basic cell reference.

Let's say you have the value 7.5 in cell A1 in the worksheet "Hours". That's the first column and first cell in that column.
Also the value 4.5 is in cell A2 in the worksheet "Hours". That's the second cell in the first column; and it's also in the second row.

Let's say you want a summary sheet. The worksheet is named "Sum". You want to sum from the hours sheet.

In A1 on Sum sheet, type:

```
=Hours!A1
```

In A2 on Sum sheet, type:

```
=Hours!A2
```

In A3 on Sum sheet, type:

```
=SUM(A1:A2)
```

A brief explanation: https://smallbusiness.chron.com/cross-reference-between-excel-spreadsheets-41572.html

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I have explained it very well, though I would be able to attach an example, but doesn't seem like you can?

Comment: Each week we are provided a sheet from payroll to fill in, but it is very manual and take about 2 hours to complete. I want to be able to just copy a feed sheet into the workbook and all cells just update automatically.

Comment: Tom, I think your goal is probably do-able, but I don't think you are going to be successful without learning some  Excel basics, and it's possible what you are looking for is more advanced Excel usage than you realize.